# Ordering large numeric values

Tags: r

When I try to order a large number data set
using

```
test <- StatePop[with(StatePop, order(StatePop$CENSUS_2010_POP, StatePop$state.name)), ]
```

It gives me :

[image: It sorts only some numeric places I believe, I am looking for a proper ascending order]

Comment: They look like character vectors to me. Try changing to numeric using `as.numeric()`. You can't have a comma.

Comment: please make your question reproducible, and share example data instead of pasting pictures of it.

Comment: You should typically include a small reproducible example.  In this case, include some data using `dput`, not an image.

Comment: when using `with` you only need to `test <- StatePop[with(StatePop, order(CENSUS_2010_POP, state.name)), ]`

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one.

Commas in the large numbers was a problem. 
I used gsub to remove commas and tried to order again.

it worked!

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting the answer! It would be a *much better* answer and maybe even garner some upvotes if you actually showed the code you used, maybe `gsub` and `as.numeric`....